# How do I extract the second number pairing from a character string?

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

If I have a column with character variables that look like "1000_D_22", "1002M_26", and "1014_17_2/3/2019", how do I strip the characters so that I get "22", "26", and "17"?

Answer (score 2):

`strsplit` by non-number characters `\D` in regex, and then select `[` the second value:

```
x <-  c("1000_D_22", "1002M_26", "1014_17_2/3/2019")
sapply(strsplit(x, "\\D+"), `[`, 2)
#[1] "22" "26" "17"
```